# Random forest in ecognition

Tags: random, ecognition

I'm using eCognition to mapping roof materials from SPOT 6 image. I have used nearest neighbour classification but the result is not so good. I'm trying to apply a random forest classifier if it is available in eCognition (maybe need to plug in).